# How do I add an additional IPv6 address to /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, ipv6

this question [How do I add an additional IP address to /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313877/how-do-i-add-an-additional-ip-address-to-etc-network-interfaces) mostly asks what i want except that i want to add more *IPv6* addresses in the same interface `eth0` without incrementing to `eth0.1` and so on. the `ifconfig` command does IPv6 like `ifconfig eth0 add ...`  so ... **how can i add more IPv6 addresses** to `eth0`?

Comment: it would be nice if there was a practical way to do a whole /64

Comment: You can find some information about using a full /64 block on a single host here: http://serverfault.com/questions/590038/adding-a-whole-ipv6-64-block-to-an-network-interface-on-debian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the question you reference, the [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/313881/211771) shows the equivalent solution for IPv4. In the case of IPv6, the `/etc/network/interfaces` file should contain something like this:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 2001:db8:1:2::2
  netmask 64
  # Add additional IPv6 addresses when $IFACE goes up
  up ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:1:2::3/64 dev $IFACE
  up ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:1:2::4/64 dev $IFACE
  # Remove them when $IFACE goes down
  down ip -6 addr del 2001:db8:1:2::3/64 dev $IFACE
  down ip -6 addr del 2001:db8:1:2::4/64 dev $IFACE
```

You will need the `iproute2` package installed, but you should use `ip` instead of `ifconfig` anyway.

---

For adding a whole /64 to an interface: There are some Q&As in [serverfault.se](http://serverfault.stackexchange.com), like "[Adding a whole IPv6 /64 block to an network interface on debian](https://serverfault.com/q/590038/54102)" or "[Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?](https://serverfault.com/q/209203/54102)". Maybe they can help you.

Comment: that local block route feature works so all i need to do now is get that added so it puts it back on reboot

Answer (score 27):

It would appear (tested with ifupdown version 0.7.53.1) that we can add several `iface eth0 inet6` stanzas to the `interfaces` file, which is more declarative than the accepted answer. The following code instructs the ifupdown suite to use stateless autoconfiguration and two additional static IPv6 addresses for the `eth0` network interface:

```
iface eth0 inet6 auto
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 3ffe:ffff::dead:beef
  netmask 32
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address 3ffe:ffff::c0de:d00d
  netmask 32
```

Comment: This is the "proper" answer - for IPv6 and IPv4!

Comment: in my case your answer did not work, but the approved one above did work. I am not sure why it might since it is a virtual machine (xen)?

Comment: It would be useful to know what version of ifupdown you use. Can you look into the manpage of ifconfig?

Comment: While this works, it may not do what you want with respect to private addressing and router advertisements. See https://salsa.debian.org/debian/ifupdown/blob/master/inet6.defn for what actually happens. It seems like the order matters here for each of the `inet6` statements. It may make sense to have a single `auto` declaration and then use `post-up` to add the addresses via `ip -6 add` and `pre-down` to remove it.

Comment: Props for the `dead:beef` and `c0de:d00d`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did for multiple v6 addresses in interfaces file. First thing to consider is there cannot be two gateways, so you add a route below the second address.

```
iface ens802f0 inet6 static
    address 1154::1154
    netmask 64
    gateway 1154::130


iface ens802f0 inet6 static
     address 1063::105
     netmask 64
     up ip -6 route add 1063::/64 via 1063::254 || true
```

Answer (score 1):

I was puzzled, too.  But you can just give as many address lines you like.  And it works.

Example:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
  address fd12:3456:789a::dead:beef/64
  address fd12:3456:789a::c0de:d00d/64
  # add more address lines here
  gateway fe80::1
```

Apply without interruption with:

```
ifup eth0
```

You can also remove addresses this way.  No need for `ifdown`.

FYI:

```
# dpkg -l ifupdown | cat
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-================================================
rc  ifupdown       0.8.36       amd64        high level tools to configure network interfaces

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```

Notes:

You can even use IPv4 addresses to improve readability.  For example on ProxMox I map the IPv6 of a VM based on the internal IPv4 of the VM, which gives addresses like:

`fd01:7e57::192.168.0.1/64` provided your IPv6 prefix is `/64`.

`fd12:3456:789a` in the example above is from the private IPv6 area `fd00::/8`, which is similar to a private net on IPv4 like `10.0.0.0/8`.  Replace `12:3456:789a` with 40 random bits.  This leaves 16 bits for subnets to form a `/64` (in IPv6, networks cannot go beyond `/64`, so this should always be the biggest address mask you can see on properly IPv6 enabled networks).

RIPE even writes:

> Assigning prefixes longer than /56 is strongly discouraged, so your
> choices are: If you want a simple addressing plan use a /48 for each
> end-user

Read:

- "Official" (static) allocations from your ISP should give you a /48.
- Dynamic allocations (from the ISP to your router), usually give you a /56.
- And internally on our network, you use a /64, so you can split up the /56 into 256 distinct networks for your own needs.

If you see a /64 on your router this does not mean, your ISP is nuts.  Many routers default to /64 if not configured otherwise.  Usually all ISPs allow routers to request a /56.

So on the other side (Server) you can safely assume, that all IPs which use the same prefix according to /56 come from the same network.